# Почему не получается сослаться на уникальный ключ из сторонней таблицы?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id         SERIAL          NOT NULL,
    chat_id    BIGINT          NOT NULL,
    username   VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    full_name  VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(chat_id),
    UNIQUE(id)
);
```

Почему при попытке сослаться на уникальный ключ(поле id), выводится ошибка

> there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table
> "users"

На уникальный ключ нельзя ссылаться из вне?

Comment: Замечу, что в высшей степени странно, что таблица с юзерами в качестве первичного ключа имеет идентификатор чата, а не свой собственный. А что вообще происходит? Что значит сослаться? Идеально - как воспроизвести у себя такое?

Comment: Отлично все ссылается http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6a43b/1 в чем вообще проблемы ? А вообще два уникальных id в одной таблице это очень странно. Я бы понял если бы были уникальные поля из реального мира, но не два заведомо суррогатных значения. Похоже что вы решаете какую то задачу не с той стороны